Sudden bug in the publish function of google seets
Since today (it could be introduced during the last 7 days) google sheets has a bug in the "Publish" user interface.
the "Publish" button does not exist to validate the choice and it always returns to "entire document" instead of a specific tab that was published previously.
Here is a picture of the user interface, showing the place where the publish button should appear but doesn't ...


1.  It'd be better off to post this at docs community forum since the product experts there has the provision to escalate it to google if they think its valid. 2. the screenshot shows that one specific tab 19.8.2024 is already published. there would be stop publishing option under Published content & settings. Trying to understand why there would be another Publish button at the arrow point in the screenshot?!

@rockinfreakshow - thanks for the advice, I did the post in the referred forum. Concerning your question: it is not possible to change the publishing, give it a try, you'll see. Also some days ago it still was possible to publish a selection of tabs - all this is not possible with the new interface.

You mean to say selective few tabs cant be selected and published? Like if the sheet has 5 tabs & you wish to publish just the tab 1 and tab 2?
